# What data structure should I organize my data in?

Tags: python

Beginner programmer here. I'm given a csv file. One column contains dates, another column contains a string that either says 'Absent' or 'Present'. (the dates are also a string)

What I'm trying to accomplish is to group a percentage of the amount of kids that showed up for a particular date.

So like maybe for an example as the end result I'd have a list of lists that contains the date and the percentage of students that attended like so

```
Attendance = [[08/22/2016, 89.013],[08/26/2016, 84.33]]
```

The only problem is I don't know how to get to that point.

Could someone show me how I'd get from point A to point B?

Edit: for this example let's say

```
file_o = open(csvFile, 'r')
csvF = csv.reader(file_o)
for line in csvF:
    line[0] # contains date
    line[1] # contains 'Absent' or 'Present
```

Comment: This is a really broad question. There are several ways to do this. Break the task down; are you able to read csv data into python lists (step 1)? You should view A --> B in a number of small, atomic steps and tackle those one by one.

Comment: Add a few line example CSV file and a python program that reads it - even if that program is totally broken. Try the csv module.

Comment: You could use a `dict` where key is the date, and value is a list of absent/present. Read each row of the csv and update the dict. Then run through the dict again and replace its lists with percentage present.

Comment: @tdelaney yes, that's precisely what I want although I don't know how to achieve that. edit: I've updated the original post with some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dict` seems like the easiest approach. Use it to record a list of present/absent values for each date and then sum those up. Since you want only certain dates, I've initialized the tracking dictionary with those dates and just ignore the others.

(note: updated to a working example)

```
import csv

# write a test file
open('mytest.csv', 'w').write("""08/22/2016,Present,Fiona
08/22/2016,Absent,Ralph
08/23/2016,Present,Fiona
08/23/2016,Absent,Ralph
08/24/2016,Present,Fiona
08/24/2016,Absent,Ralph
08/25/2016,Present,Fiona
08/25/2016,Absent,Ralph



""")

# initialize tracker with wanted dates.
wanted_dates = ['08/22/2016', '08/25/2016', '08/30/2016']
tracker = {wanted:[] for wanted in wanted_dates}

with open('mytest.csv', newline='') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            date = row[0]
            # only add wanted dates
            if date in tracker:
                present = row[1].lower()
                tracker[date].append(present == 'present')

# create final report. make a copy of tracker's values because we
# will change tracker during enumeration.
for date, present_list in tracker.items():
    if not present_list:
        # no data, so show 0
        present_list = [0]
    tracker[date] = float(sum(present_list))/len(present_list) * 100

for date, percent in sorted(tracker.items()):
    print('{} {:2.2f}'.format(date, percent))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, at the moment when I try out the code in my program, I'm getting a ValueError: too many values to unpack. Also let's say I already had a list of dates that I specifically needed to look for in the file then "append" the date and the list of 'Present' and "Absent' to the dict. This may solve the ValueError too, since it won't be going through every date in the file.

Comment: Also my program was telling me that end='' was an invalid keyword argument, so I replaced it with 'r' , was this okay to do?

Comment: That should have been `newline=''` (and I'm assuing you use python 3). I sometimes get confused between `print` and `open`... you'd think they'd use the same names. Also, you must be reading the row differently than I do. to get an unpack error. You could test the length of the row because csv will read empty lines too. You could put the wanted dates in a set, and check for inclusion before adding to the dict.

Comment: how about posting your updated code below the original so I can see better what is going on.

Comment: Well I've tried to implement your code directly to see if it'd return anything, the only thing I changed were the rows. for instance: date = row[1].lower() and present = row[5].

Comment: It seems as though the first part of your code is working, though when it gets down to for date, present_list , that's where it throws the error. EDIT: First part is confirmed working it's spitting back out {'date': [True, False, True, etc.]}

Comment: I've updated to a working example so we can both talk about the same thing. You have unpacking errors, and other things I don't see,.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! The unpacking errors are gone using your updated code as a template.